# Python socket with ssl to prevent middle attack

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I have an app which uses RSA assymetric encryption and sockets. But after I read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189468/why-can-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-not-happen-with-rsa), I tried to use ssl sockets. I tried a bunch of codes. Here is the server:

```
import socket, ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)

sock.bind(('some ip', 9999))
sock.listen(1)
cl, ip = sock.accept()
cl.send(b'hi client')
print(cl.recv(1024))
```

and here is the client:

```
import socket, ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)

sock.connect(('same ip as server', 9999))
sock.send(b'hi server')
print(sock.recv(1024))
```

But I keep getting this on the server side when the client connects (not when client is not running):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/avishah/PycharmProjects/Math/SocketTest/Server.py", line 9, in <module>
    cl, ip = sock.accept()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1355, in accept
    newsock = self.context.wrap_socket(newsock,
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1125)
```

and this on the client:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/avishah/PycharmProjects/Math/SocketTest/Client.py", line 8, in <module>
    sock.connect(('192.168.43.254', 9999))
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1342, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1333, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1125)
```

I also added ciphers as part of the `wrap_socket` but that would lead to the same thing.

I actually want a minimalist example of both server and client with the ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

The security of SSL/TLS is based on two principles: a) encrypting the traffic against sniffing and manipulation and b) making sure to communicate with the right peer. The latter is essential since otherwise an active man in the middle could simply impersonate the server, i.e. the communication would still be encrypted but it would be between client and attacker and not client and intended server instead.

Verifying that the client communicates with the right server is usually done with certificates. Your code does not use any certificates. Since for security reasons the ciphers which are enabled by default all require certificates you'll end up with no possible ciphers to use, i.e.

```
  ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1125)
```

> I actually want a minimalist example of both server and client

The [official documentation of the ssl module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) includes such examples, so please see there.

Comment: So I need certificates... The wrap socket takes few types of certificates, there's certfile (I tried this, I passed certifii.where() to this), ca_certs and cert_reqs. Which one do I need to use and what should I pass? The official documentation doesn't seem to have the server side code, so I assumed it's a server side problem (which it might be, still).

Comment: @AviShah: *"The official documentation doesn't seem to have the server side code"* - it does. There are three clearly described code blocks exactly where I've linked to: client with default context, client with custom context, server.